# Get the oldest date from array dd/mm/yy

Tags: php

i try to get the "oldest person" in my example address book.

This is the address book array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => Bill
            [Lastname] => McKnight
            [Gender] => Male
            [Birthday] => 16/03/77
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => Paul
            [Lastname] => Robinson
            [Gender] => Male
            [Birthday] => 15/01/85
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => Gemma
            [Lastname] => Lane
            [Gender] => Female
            [Birthday] => 20/11/91
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => Sarah
            [Lastname] => Stone
            [Gender] => Female
            [Birthday] => 20/09/80
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => Wes
            [Lastname] => Jackson
            [Gender] => Male
            [Birthday] => 14/08/74
        )
)
```

With my code I get always the last array..

```
$oldestPerson = 0;
for($i=0; $i<count($persons);$i++){
    if($persons[$i]['Birthday'] > $persons[$i+1]['Birthday']){
        $oldestPerson = $persons[$i];
    }
}

print_r($oldestPerson);
```

How can I compare correctly the birthdays?

Comment: make the Birthday a real DateTime Object, or a timestamp to be campareable. Right now you compare strings. _OR_ transform them inside your loop before you compare them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$oldestPerson = null;
$oldestBirthday = new DateTime();  // preparing to save the oldest found birthday to compare against

for($i=0; $i<count($persons);$i++){
    // create a DateTime Object out of the birthday-string
    $birthday = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/y", $persons[$i]['Birthday']);

    if($birthday < $oldestBirthday){  // compare this to the oldest (=smallest) saved one
        $oldestPerson = $persons[$i]; // update
        $oldestBirthday = $birthday;  // update
    }
}

print_r($oldestPerson);
```

Comment: Quite simple, yes. Use [DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to get the difference (see the examples)

Comment: If the date string is a well-formed US format date, you can just do ```new DateTime($someDateString)```

Comment: @DarraghEnright If, yes. But this is a well-formed UK format date and going via constructor throws an error.

Comment: It is indeed. I must be going blind—I misread the date format o_O